# Unable to start debugging on the web server

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, iis-7

I have now tried to get our webservice to run with debug from within Visual Studio 2008 a long time with no success. This project worked great before and works fine on other computers, I suppose that there is something wrong with the IIS7 settings.

The main project in the solution is a WFC service that is used as a simple webservice (svc). All projects in this solution are set to use .NET framework 3.5.

When running the service with the built in IIS(VS) it seems to work just fine but as soon as the IIS7 is used a dialog appears and states:

> Unable to start debugging on the web
>   server. Check for one of the following

The following is done in IIS7 :

1. Application created that points to the webservice
2. DefaultAppPool (.NET framework 4 Integrated)(ApplicationPoolIdentity) is used
3. Browsing the service works fine (It shows the WSDL)
4. When changing the DefaultAppPool to .NET framework 2.0 it states somthing about static file problems but I can´t see anything missing from the Webservice > Handler Mappings?
5. Enable 32-bit Application is set to true on the DefaultAppPool.
6. I have runned `aspnet_regiis` from all the .net version in order
7. Set `debug="true"` in the `web.config`
8. I was not at first able to get the webservice starting at all to solve this I hade to comment out a couple of rows in the web.config :

   ```
   <configSections>
     <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
     <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
       <!--<section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />-->
       <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <!--<section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />-->
        <!--<section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />-->
        <!--<section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />-->
        <!--<section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />-->
       </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
     </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
   ```

(scriptResourceHandler, jsonSerialization, profileService, authenticationService, roleService)

How to get this running with debug?

Comment: Are you running VS in elevated user mode?

Comment: Om not sure what "elevated user mode" means but I am running VS as administrator.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. In such case I can't help. It always just worked for me, however I usually let VS create the IIS site for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running under IIS, you don't "start" but attach to the running process.

In the ApplicationPool settings, disable pinging, or IIS will recycle the pool during your debug session.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using a "mycustomhostname.service" host name.  I had to add it to the hosts file entry in "C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc"

```
127.0.0.1 mycustomhostname.service
```